# Getting a null pointer exception in logcat when using radiobutton.getText()

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, radio-button

In my android app I am using two radiobuttons.

One of them is selected and its value is stored in database but `rdbbut.getText()` is throwing a null pointer exception in its `Onclick` Method here:

```
checkLogin(email, password, rdbbut.getText().toString())
```

My code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    rggrp = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
    rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);
    final int selectedId = rggrp.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    // Progress dialog
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);

    // Session manager
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

    // Check if user is already logged in or not
    if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
        // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    // Login button Click Event
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

            rdbbut = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
            // Check for empty data in the form
            if (email.trim().length() > 0 && password.trim().length() > 0) {
                // login user
                checkLogin(email, password, rdbbut.getText().toString());
            } else {
                // Prompt user to enter credentials
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter the credentials!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        }

    });

    // Link to Register Screen
    btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });

}

/**
 * function to verify login details in mysql db
 * */
private void checkLogin(final String email, final String password,
        final CharSequence charSequence) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String tag_string_req = "req_login";

    pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
                    hideDialog();

                    try {
                        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                        // Check for error node in json
                        if (!error) {
                            // user successfully logged in
                            // Create login session
                            session.setLogin(true);

                            // Launch main activity
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                                    MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            // Error in login. Get the error message
                            String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // JSON error
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    hideDialog();
                }
            }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting parameters to login url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("tag", "login");
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);
            params.put("type", (String) charSequence);

            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}

private void showDialog() {
    if (!pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.show();
}

private void hideDialog() {
    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Logcat :

```
06-02 23:36:55.638: D/AndroidRuntime(1074): Shutting down VM
06-02 23:36:55.638: W/dalvikvm(1074): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
06-02 23:36:55.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1074): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-02 23:36:55.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1074): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-02 23:36:55.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at com.kirti.login_screen.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:99)
06-02 23:36:55.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
06-02 23:36:55.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
06-02 23:36:55.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-02 23:36:55.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-02 23:36:55.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-02 23:36:55.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
06-02 23:36:55.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-02 23:36:55.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-02 23:36:55.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
06-02 23:36:55.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-02 23:36:55.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1074):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-02 23:36:58.688: I/Process(1074): Sending signal. PID: 1074 SIG: 9
```

My Login.xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"


android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:background="@color/bg_login"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:hint="@string/hint_email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/input_login"
            android:textColorHint="@color/input_login_hint" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:hint="@string/hint_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/input_login"
            android:textColorHint="@color/input_login_hint" />




        <!-- Login Button -->
    <RadioGroup
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="80dp"

   android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
   android:weightSum="1"
   android:id="@+id/radioGroup">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="@string/owner" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="@string/bikers" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:background="@color/btn_login_bg"
            android:text="@string/btn_login"
            android:textColor="@color/btn_login" />

        <!-- Link to Login Screen -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLinkToRegisterScreen"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="@string/btn_link_to_register"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: which line is `LoginActivity.java:99` in your code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
rdbbut = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
```

To

```
rdbbut = (RadioButton) MainActivity.this.findViewById(selectedId);
```

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
String radiotext =  (RadioButton)MainActivity.this.findViewById(rggrp.getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString();
```

Comment: This does the same. And in that case, `this` refers the `onClick()`

Comment: I edited the answer, if you want use more code for do the same, you are welcome.

Comment: The problem is not using more code to do the same thing. You must think about performance since the `findViewById` is slower than check with `if` and `else`. So no matter how many lines of code you use, it's better think about performance always.

Comment: If you want performance use OnCheckedChangeListener in every radiobutton and set a final variable String with the radio gettext and call it in the onClick and complete the action if this is not null. Is the correct way.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, but this would change the whole code, and I think our friend above wouldn't like to do such thing though.

Comment: Well, less code and best performance, two simple options, and third option +Shnkc solution for your code, you can choose whatever, the important is to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following code:

```
// Login button Click Event
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View view) {

        String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
        String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

        // Check for empty data in the form
        if (email.trim().length() > 0 && password.trim().length() > 0) {

            String _radioButtontext;

            if(rb1.getId() == selectedId){

                _radioButtontext = rb1.getText();

            }
            else{

                _radioButtontext = rb2.getText();

            }

            // login user
            checkLogin(email, password, _radioButtontext);
        } else {
            // Prompt user to enter credentials
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Please enter the credentials!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Thnks for the answer,,it Solved my problem

Comment: That's great! So please accept it as right answer for the people who have the same problem :)